# VLOOKUP problem with value from =arrayformula(iferror(regexextract

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup, regexextract

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP to pull data from one tab in a Google Sheets workbook into another tab. The VLOOKUP formula works if the value being searched for is `100103`, but not the cell reference G2 (which displays `100103`).

**Formula In G2**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(regexextract(F2:F, "ID#\d+"), "\d+")))
```

**Shared Copy Of Original Google Sheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LNiRPoi-3ZtViIL8JhJ_Qd2jo3XUEpfMLwlmlOz1jTs/edit#gid=895445914

**VLOOKUP Formula Being Used**

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,workshops!$E:$K,2, FALSE)
```

**Error Received**

```
Error
Did not find value '100103' in VLOOKUP evaluation.
```

**Google Product Forum Post**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MLv28H7msmw

The user is experiencing a similar problem. They received a solution, but not an explanation of the solution. As a result, I'm not sure how to adjust my formula(s).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between the string of characters "100103" and the number 100103. Your workshops tab contains numbers. `regexextract` returns a string. To make things work, convert string to number using `value` after `regexextract`:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(value(regexextract(regexextract(F2:F, "ID#\d+"), "\d+"))))
```

Comment: Seriously, you are AMAZING! It worked perfectly. Thanks a MILLION.